# Grails- groovy sql each row to be displayed in gsp view

Tags: grails, gsp

I want to display the result of sql each row from the service code to my gsp view.

My Service code is:

```
def health()  
{  
    def schemaList      = [:]  
    groovy.sql.Sql sql = new groovy.sql.Sql(dataSource);  
    sql.eachRow("SELECT SOURCE, count(1) as COUNT from fact group by SOURCE");  
    ArrayList returnResults = []  
    sqlStatement.eachRow(sqlString)
    {  
        returnResults<<it.toRowResults()   
    }   
    sqlStatement.close()   
    return[returnMap:returnResults]  
}
```

My Controller Code is:

```
def stats =  {    
   def health = AccessLogService.heath()  
   render (template:'healthview', model:[health:health])
}
```

My gsp view is as follows:

```
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
  <meta name="layout" content="admin" />
  <title>Health</title>
</head>

<body>
  <SCRIPT language="JavaScript">
  </SCRIPT>
  <br />
  <br />
  <font style='font-size:14px;font-weight:bold;'>Health Condition</font>
  <div id='overall'>
    <g:if test="${health.size() > 0}">
      <table border="1">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Source</th>
            <th>Count</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <g:each in="${health}" status="i" var="thisRecord">
            <tr>
              <td>${thisRecord.SOURCE}</td>
              <td>${thisRecord.COUNT}</td>
            </tr>
          </g:each>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </g:if>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I am not able to see the results of my query in gsp view? Where I am going wrong.

Comment: Given that your service returns a map, your data is under `returnMap` and thus your model looks like `health.returnMap` not just `health`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are trying to get the wrong key of your model.

you service returns a hash `[returnMap:returnResults]` so your controller renders the model: `[health:health]` -> `[health:[returnMap:returnResults]]`.

thus in your gsp you should refer to `health.returnMap` to see the list:

```
 <g:if test="${health.returnMap}">
   ...
      <g:each in="${health.returnMap}" status="i" var="thisRecord">
        <tr>
          <td>${thisRecord.SOURCE}</td>
          <td>${thisRecord.COUNT}</td>
        </tr>
      </g:each>
   ...
 </g:if>
```

UPDATE:

the code looks strange... this is how it should be:

```
ArrayList returnResults = []
sql.eachRow("SELECT SOURCE, count(1) as COUNT from fact group by SOURCE"){
  returnResults << it.toRowResults()
}
```

Comment: I am using Grails 1.7.3 version. When I do as suggested by you, I get Message: No signature of method: groovy.sql.Sql.eachRow() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String) values: [SELECT distinct SOURCE,count(1) as COUNT from fact group by source] Possible solutions: eachRow(java.lang.String, groovy.lang.Closure)
Class: ChangePasswordFilter

Comment: Thanks. I figured that out. My doubt is I want to show the fields for example the SOURCE and Count as table form in my gsp view. In my controller I am returning render (template:'healthview', model:[health:health.collect{ it.values() }]) I am using the same gsp code shown above , but I am not able to show it neatly in table form

Answer (score 0):

Where is the `sqlStatement` variable declared in your service? I think that is the error.
And an advice you need to debug your program. for example, Test if the service returns result by:

- running your app debug mode
- using log.debug
- using println

or if you are doing these and have seen any erorrs on your console post that here.

Comment: this could be a comment, but not an answer